# Java TrayIcon: addMouseListener -> distinguish between single click and double click?

Tags: java, click, trayicon

I would like to show an alert when clicking on the TrayIcon, and show the main window when double clicking on it. I am having issues capturing the double click event: every time I double click, two single click events are fired.

I am using the following code:

```
        trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
             if (e.getClickCount() == 1 && e.getButton() == 1) {                
                 trayIcon.displayMessage(...);              
             } else if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && e.getButton() == 1) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I prevent the single click event stealing the double click ?

Comment: Checking the double click first...think of it like this, a double click is two clicks of the mouse button in short succession, meaning it will trigger your MouseListener twice...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: It's the first thing I tried - it made no difference !

Comment: Okay, another idea is to use something like a Swing Timer, with a small delay which is longer then the double click delay. On the first click, you start the timer, on the double click, you stop the timer. If the timer can complete, then you have a single click....but there must be a cleaner way...

Answer (score 1):

This is an imperfect solution to an imperfect problem. By it's very nature, a double click will generate two mouse events, but a double click is any two clicks which occur within a short period of time between each other.

So, you could insert a small delay on the first click, which if triggered, will "assume" that the event is only a single click.

This example uses a Swing `Timer` set to 300 milliseconds (you could try 250-275, but I found 300 to be just right).  When it detects the first click, it starts the timer, if it detects a second click, it stops the timer, otherwise the timer is allowed to execute after the 300 millisecond delay, which assumes a double click...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication314 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication314();
    }

    public JavaApplication314() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
            label = new JLabel("...");
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(label);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void doOneClick() {
            label.setText("One Click");
        }

        protected void doTwoClicks() {
            label.setText("Two Clicks");
        }

        public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

            private Timer oneClickTimer;

            public MouseHandler() {
                oneClickTimer = new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        doOneClick();
                    }
                });
                oneClickTimer.setRepeats(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    oneClickTimer.stop();
                    doTwoClicks();
                } else if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    oneClickTimer.restart();
                }
            }



        }

    }

}
```

Another option might be would be to use a meta-key (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>) to change the state of the menu on a single click

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && !e.isConsumed()) {
     e.consume();
     ...
}
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit? Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How Do I Write A Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not work - same problem :( The code "if (e.getClickCount() == 2" never gets executed because the other one steals it